# Why does multiprocessing.Pool not start? For a simple I/O case with some processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to read some cvs's into dataframes, do some processing and save the results again (this time pickeling them). I'm running a jupyter-notebook on Windows 10.

```
def clean_logs(filename : str):
    print('Started reading {fname}'.format(fname=filename))
    df = pd.read_csv('../datasets/complete_logs/{fname}'.format(fname=filename), index_col=0)
    print('Finished reading {fname}'.format(fname=filename))
    new_df = clean_logs_df(df)
    print('Finished cleaning {fname}'.format(fname=filename))
    new_df.to_pickle('../datasets/complete_logs_cleaned/{fname}.pkl'.format(fname=filename[:-4]))
```

I only added the prints so I could follow my code while running. Basically it takes a filename, reads that file, processes it and saves it again.

When I simply do:

```
for fname in logs_files:
    clean_logs(fname)
```

All works fine as it should and I get all the prints.
However if I try this:

```
n_threads = mp.cpu_count()

with mp.Pool(n_threads) as pool:
    try:
        pool.map(clean_logs, logs_files)
    except Exception:
        print(format_exc(sys.exc_info()))
```

I do not get a single print. For some reason it just blocks my jupyter-notebook forever. Can someone provide me some insight on this and why it could be happening?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I've run code similar to the multi-"threaded" version, on Manjaro Linux without any problem. And yes, mp.cpu_count() correctly returns me 12, nothing weird there.

Comment: Well I can't see the important `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause. Is it inside of your code?

Comment: It's running on jupyter-notebook, there is no main. Is it needed? I've been able to run it as a script outside jupyter-notebook, inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause. On Linux I was able to run this code on jupyter-notebook without the main clause.

Comment: Could you pls show us more code? Because I would like to know more of your code to give a better answer. At this moment I can't really say why it doesn't work. (PS: Show the code with the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause pls.
For example: How do you save your files in `log_files`? Do you use a function for it? When do you fill this list?